# WCF Client error after pool recycle (IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, pool

I have a **website** deployed on a server which responds about *1,000 requests per minute*. The website has defined a **static** var what is a **WCF Client**:

```cs
    private static WebServicesClient client = WebServicesClientInitializer();

    //And the initializer is:

    private static WebServicesClient WebServicesClientInitializer()
    {
        var client = new WebServicesClient(EndPointConfigName, EndPointConfigAddress);

        var behavior = new SecurityBehavior { Inspector = new SecurityTokenInspector(Username, Password) };
        client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Insert(0, behavior);

        iMessageLogging = new MessageLoggingInspector();
        var loggingBehavior = new LoggingBehavior { MessageLogInspector = iMessageLogging };
        client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(loggingBehavior);

        return client;
    }
```

The problem is that **after pool recycle (IIS)**, sometimes (*not allways!*), the website begins to respond much slower. Next image show the server performance before and after pool recycle. The drop in the server performance is due that the server attends many less queries per minute, because the WCF client returns results much more slowly.

**Any idea why the WCF Client works slower after the pool recycle?**

[Before-After Pool Recycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S4p9.png)

Comment: I bet that you app pool restarts with a minimum amount of memory and memory will increases over time as more requests are processed. The memory climbs to a maximum amount. I bet that you can configure your app pool to reserve a larger chunk of memory and more threads. I would test this by setting high configuration values for memory and or threads and restart and compare and refine until a balance is found.

Comment: You need more performance profiling to know the runtime behaviors. The current observation does not help much. If possible open a support case with Microsoft.